# How to pass data to angular 2 router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need to pass data to angular router outlet. It can be done using parameter or optional parameter (Query Parameter). But my question is there any other way to pass data to router outlet other than using parameter passing. what is the better way to accomplish this.

Comment: You can use `data` in the router config.

Comment: Define "better". You can use a shared service.

Comment: Or you can use a [resolve guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard) on the route

Answer (score 0):

(1) You can use `data` property like below :

```
{path: 'user/:id', component: UserDetailComponent , data: [{userName: 'testname'}]}
```

and consume in Component like :

```
export class UserDetailComponent {
  userId : string;
  userName: string;

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.userId = route.snapshot.params['id'];     
    this.userName = route.snapshot.data[0]['userName'];
  }
}
```

(2) or you can create service which share data across. like :

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService{
private userData: IUserData;
  constructor(){}
  getUserData() : IUserData[] {
    return this.userData;
  }
setUserData(data) {
    this.userData = data;
  }
}
```

further, inject the service in desired component :

```
constructor(private userService: UserService)
```

Use [localStorage](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage) to persist data., by importing it import { LocalStorageModule } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

Comment: Is it possible to assign dynamic values to data property instead assigning it in router config.

Comment: If we use shared service for data storage, i end up with loss of data when page gets refreshed. Thank You.

Comment: yes it possible to assign the dynamic property through `[routerlink]`, [readmore](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html)

Comment: Thank u for ur reply...But i don't want to make my visible in the url. But what i want is define data for router at the run time instead in the route configuration.

Comment: then please use service, and declare the service at app level, with `providers: [yourServiceName]`, by this service instance will be shared by the your main `component (for eg., AppComponent)` and its children components.

Comment: Using service is fine,but my problem is the loss of data when the page gets reloaded.

Comment: okay, the data loss is normal. as service is reinitialized. So there 2 ways either you initiaze the data again or use [localStorage.](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage). by importing it `import { LocalStorageModule } from 'angular-2-local-storage';` [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-local-storage)